# Fitting random intercept and slope in lmer for lme4.

Tags: lme4-nlme

If I would like to fit random intercept and slope and if I write it as (color|writer) compared to (1+color|writer), are they the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `(1+color|writer)` and `(color|writer)` are the same. The intercept is always assumed, unless it is explicitly suppressed, e.g. via `(0+color|writer)`, where only the slope is random.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. You've saved my life.

Comment: see also http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq#modelspec